# I'm trying to count the time any object touches the trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    timeee += Time.deltaTime;
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    timeee = 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is; incrementing the timeee variable every second until any object starts touching the **trigger** until it stops touching. And when it's 7 seconds to finish the game. I wrote the code as in the picture. However, the code starts counting but stops counting after a while.

```
void Update()
{
    if (timeee > 7)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver1");
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it touches the **trigger**, but the **timeee** variable does not increase after a point. When another object touches it, it starts to increase again.

Comment: in general why not simply do the check and scene transition also in `OnTriggerStay2D` ?

Comment: You reset the timee variable if an object leaves. It looks like a kinda marble version of Tetris or something any chance the new marbles go in and out of the trigger area?

Comment: I could not understand what you mean. Can you be more clear? @derHugo

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, when any object touches the trigger, I set the timeee to 0. And yes, any object can enter the trigger area.

Comment: I mean you could do `if (timeee > 7){ ... }` right after `timeee += ...` within `OnTriggerStay2D` and delete `Update`

Comment: I Tried but it not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I change the code like this:

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    IsInRange = true;
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    IsInRange = false;
    timeee = 0; 
}
```

Update function:

```
void Update()
 {
     if (isInRange)
     {
         timeee += Time.deltaTime;
     }
     else
     {
         timeee = 0;
     }

     if (timeee > 7)
     {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver1");
     }
 }
```